# The correct way to create a file path on Android 10.0

Tags: android, uri, filepath, mediastore, android-10.0

I'm using this library to [GIFEncoder](https://github.com/waynejo/android-ndk-gif), to generate a GIF file from images, this library required a path at the initialization in order to save the final GIF with it as follows :

```
gifEncoder.init(width, height, FILEPATH , GifEncoder.EncodingType.ENCODING_TYPE_NORMAL_LOW_MEMORY);
```

for that I tried to create a GIF file and give the library the path:

```
 String gifFileName = "APP" + Constants.CURRENT_DATE + ".gif";
 String pictureFolderPath = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + Constants.BaseFolder;
 String pathImageKey = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;

 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            Uri insertedUri = getGIFUri(context, gifFileName, pictureFolderPath);
            String correctPath = queryFilePath4Uri(context, insertedUri, pathImageKey);
            Log.d("Correct Path", correctPath.toString());
            return correctPath;
}
```

in log cat I can see the path :

```
2020-06-07 11:11:48.878 7570-7745/maa.app.abc D/Correct Path: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MYAPP/GIFs/APP20200607_101138.gif
```

but when I test it on Android 10 **(Emulator)**, nothing happens the saved GIF becomes empty with 0 octets as size, and here's the `getGIFUri` and `queryFilePath4Uri` methods :

```
 fun getGIFUri(context: Context, fileName: String, dirName: String): Uri? {
        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName)
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "APP")
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/gif")
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis())
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "$dirName/GIFs")
        }
        var result: Uri? = null
        val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
        contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values).let { insertUri ->
            result = insertUri
        }
        return result;
    }

fun queryFilePath4Uri(context: Context, uri: Uri, pathKey: String): String? {
    context.contentResolver?.query(uri, null, null, null, null)?.use {
        val isHas = it.moveToFirst()
        if (isHas) {
            val dataIndex = it.getColumnIndex(pathKey)
            if (dataIndex != -1) {
                val data = it.getString(dataIndex)
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data)) {
                    return data
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return uri.path
}
```

Comment: If you need a file system path then dont use the media store but getExternalFilesDir(). The path you used is not readable and writable under Android Q.

Comment: `queryFilePath4Uri()` Dont try to get a path if you have an uri. File time is over. Its uri time.

Comment: Hi @blackapps thank you so much for your comment, can you please show me an example if you could

Comment: Jus use getExternalFilesDir() as directory for your file. Not the one you have now.

Comment: @blackapps it doesn't mean the file will be created in the cache?, because I want to save the GIF file to the gallery later

Comment: @blackapps the GIF successfully saved but in the cache directory, how I can make it appear in the Gallery

Comment: That is not the cache but an app specific directory. You cannot get it in 'the gallery' if you use that private directory path. If you want it 'in the gallery' then use the uri obtained from the media store. Dont try to convert that uri to a path.

Comment: @blackapps thank you for the clarification, but my main goal is save the file to the gallery, should I use the DCIM or PICTURE path only without specify a folder

Comment: No. That does not make any difference. Use that uri. Ask the gif encoder library developers to add the use of an uri. Are you shure they didnt already?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using this library to GIFEncoder, to generate a GIF file from images

That library is a bit old.

> This library required a path at the initialization in order

Use a `File` based off of methods on `Context`, such as `getFilesDir()` or `getExternalFilesDir()`. Then, after the GIF is created, later move it to a public directory. Or, find a library that supports an `OutputStream` or `Uri` as a destination to write to.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it's possible to move a file from getExternalFilesDir() path to the gallery ?

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI: I would not use "move" as the verb. On Android 10+, you can store images by way of the `MediaStore`. In [this sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/vFINAL/ConferenceVideos) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Q), I use `MediaStore` this way. In my case, I am downloading a video. Your primary changes would be to the collection (to use `Images` instead) and where your `InputStream` would come from (you would use a `FileInputStream` on your `getExternalFilesDir()`-based `File`).

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI: If you had a more modern GIF library that could accept an `OutputStream` or `Uri` as the destination, then you could skip `getExternalFilesDir()` and have the library write directly to the `Uri` supplied by `MediaStore`.